# Flutter how to get state of CTRL, SHIFT and FUNCTION keys from hardware keyboard

Tags: android, ios, flutter, keyboard

In my app I have hidden status bar and need to read state and listen to change of CTRL,  SHIFT  and FUNCTION. The purpose is to make my own indicators.

Comment: Are you trying to listen keyboard?

Comment: I'm working with barcode device and want to avoid keyboard buffer listening.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for `RawKeyEvent` by adding a listener to `RawKeyboard`, like below:

```dart
// Add this in your class's initialization or your stateful widget's `initState()`
RawKeyboard.instance.addListener(onKeyEvent);

// Define your keyboard events listener function
void onKeyEvent(RawKeyEvent event) {
    // Here you have access to the state of CTRL+ALT+SHIFT keys
    ctrlPressed = event.isControlPressed;
    altPressed = event.isAltPressed;
    shiftPressed = event.isShiftPressed;
}

// Somewhere else in your class or widget, dispose the listener function
@override
void dispose() {
    RawKeyboard.instance.removeListener(onKeyEvent);

    super.dispose();
}
```

The above is more of a global or application-wide keyboard events listener solution. To enable interacting with keyboard events inside a widget, it's probably better to use Flutter's [Actions and Shortcuts](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/advanced/actions_and_shortcuts) or [CallbackShortcuts](https://master-api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CallbackShortcuts-class.html).